# Field of Redux-Form not editing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, redux-form

I have this `Field` from Redux-Form:

```
          <Field
            name="hours"
            type="number"
            initialValue="100"
            placeholder="Ingrese las horas para esta categoría"
            component={RenderInput}
            onChange={(event) => {
              handleSubmit(currentValues => this.debounceSubmitProduction({
                ...currentValues,
                hours: event.target.value,
              }))();
            }}
          />
```

And I wanted to pass an initial value to an Input component `initialValue="100"` but now, the value appears in the input but I'm not able to edit it.

This is my RenderInput component:

```
const RenderInput = ({
  input,
  type,
  disabled,
  readOnly,
  placeholder,
  meta: { touched, error },
  onKeyDown,
  innerRef,
  initialValue,
}) => (
  <div>
    <input
      {...input}
      type={type}
      value={initialValue}
      disabled={disabled}
      readOnly={readOnly}
      placeholder={placeholder}
      className={`font-300 ${touched && error && 'has-error'}`}
      onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
      ref={innerRef}
    />
  </div>
);
```

How can I edit the initial value passed to the input?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're setting the value equal to `initialValue` which does not change when you type.  You'll want to set the initial value in the redux-store when you're component is initialized and then set the `value` prop equal to the `value` returned from the store.  `onUpdate` will update the store, and should then update the UI to reflect the change.